# http-request node - basic authentication base64 encrypted

Tags: node-red

I am new to `node-red` so I need some advices how to solve the following problem: I am using the `http-request` node and because I have to use basic authentication I add the values for `user/password` on the nodes configuration page.  My test request from command line shows like:

```
curl -k --insecure -H 'Authorization: Basic cffem9vdDjph' 'https://192.168.118.1:8080/platform/1/cluster/config'
```

which works fine because I got a JSON formatted information back. As you can see `user/password` has to be base64 encrypted to make it work. I assume that the http-request nodes use my input as plain text which didn’t work.

I tried to find the line in the `www-request.js` file where this magic happens and got some ideas what to change but if I change the `/root/.node-red/node_modules/node-red-contrib-http-request/www-request.js` file restart  node-red and redeploy the flow I got the impression that my changes didn’t become active.

Next step was the introduction of several debug points in `www-request.js` with `node.warn("trace-1");` but also this debug print isn’t shown when I start to send the http request. I got the impression that I am in the wrong place with my modifications. Any idea or advice?

Comment: Your authorization header looks rather strange. What did you pass as username and what as password? What do you mean with base64 *encryption*? Base64 is an encoding

Comment: The destination storage system (192.168.118.1) expects the user/password information as base64 encrypted string. You'll get such an information (Python) by using. import base64
auth_header = base64.b64encode('root:mypassword'.decode('ascii'))
print (auth_header). Works fine

Comment: Please stop using "base64 encryption". There is no encryption at all. Its base64 encoding.

Comment: As you can see in the curl command --insecure ! Nobody expect a real encryption here ;-) I have to take what the vendors API can offer to me. No worry!

Comment: There should be no need to edit the node (or use the contrib node) the included http-request node will allow you to pass the headers for authentication

Comment: I just found this – which has to be in an additional function node so far I understood!?
------
msg.payload = "data to post";
msg.headers = {};
msg.headers['X-Auth-User'] = 'mike';
msg.headers['X-Auth-Key'] = 'fred-key';
return msg;
-----
But how is the structure in my case? 
-----
msg.payload =“192.168.118.1:8080/platform/1/cluster/config”;
msg.headers = {};
msg.headers[‘Authorization:Basic’] =  ‘cffem9vdDjph';
return msg
.
Haven’t any clue on that - sorry

Comment: I believe the "Basic" string is part of the Authorization value, not the key -- it would be much safer to use a `change` node to "Set" `msg.`payload "to" the string "192.168.118.1:8080/platform/1/cluster/config", and "Set" `msg.`header.Authorization "to" the string "Basic cffem9vdDjph"